# Animating a cube in SceneKit within SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit

Swift 5, iOS 15

A single click rotates the cube, a double click rotates it on a different axis, but a long press does nothing, unless I follow it by a double click???

Did I miss something here?

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit


struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    GameScene().environmentObject(settings)
}
}

struct GameScene: View {

@State var cameraNode = SCNNode()
@State var scene = SCNScene(named: "MyScene.scn")
@State var lightNode: SCNNode!
@State var lightNode2: SCNNode!
@State var cubeNode: SCNNode!
@State var direct = 6.0
@State var isReady = false
@State var viewAngle = 0

let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    if !isReady {
        Color.clear
        .task {
            let cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.25)
            let redMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            redMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            let greenMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            greenMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
            let blueMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            blueMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
            let yellowMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            yellowMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
            let orangeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            orangeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
            let whiteMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            whiteMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
            
            cubeGeometry.materials = [redMaterial, greenMaterial, orangeMaterial, blueMaterial, whiteMaterial, yellowMaterial]
            
            cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
            cubeNode.name = "cubeNode"
            cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
            scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
            
            cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
            cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 6, z: 6)
            cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-26), y: 0, z: 0)
            cameraNode.name = "cameraNode"
            scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
            
            let light = SCNLight()
            light.type = SCNLight.LightType.omni
            lightNode = SCNNode()
            lightNode.light = light
            lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 4, y: 4, z: 4)
            scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
            
            let light2 = SCNLight()
            light2.type = SCNLight.LightType.omni
            lightNode2 = SCNNode()
            lightNode2.light = light2
            lightNode2.position = SCNVector3(x: -4, y: -4, z: -4)
            scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode2)
            isReady = true
        }
    } else {
       SceneView(
            scene: scene,
            pointOfView: cameraNode,
            options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl, .rendersContinuously], delegate: SceneDelegate())
            .border(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
                    let rotate =
                    SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90)), around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), duration: 0.5)
                    await cubeNode.runAction(rotate)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
                    let rotate =
                    SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90)), around: SCNVector3(1,0,0), duration: 0.5)
                    await cubeNode.runAction(rotate)
                }
            }
            .onLongPressGesture {
                Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
                    let shift = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0,-1,0), duration: 0.5)
                    await cameraNode.runAction(shift)
                    print("reg")
                    settings.poke = true
                }
            }
    }
}
}

class SharedView: ObservableObject {
@Published var poke = false
@Published var cubeColor = UIColor.red
@Published var location:CGPoint? = nil
@Published var viewAngle:Float = 0
static var shared = SharedView()
}

class SceneDelegate: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
var settings = SharedView.shared
var count = 0



@MainActor
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    if settings.poke {
        renderer.scene?.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes({ (node, _ ) in
            if node.name == "cameraNode"  {
                Task {
                    let shift = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(0,-1,0), duration: 0)
                    await node.runAction(shift)
                    print("duck")
                    
                    settings.poke = false
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Everything inside the `GameScene.body` is being recreated when the `viewAngle` changes. It is bad practice to put declarations in the `body`

Comment: Snide comments? I don't think I have done any of those, what do you consider snide? Honest question. I didn't mean to be snide.

Comment: I rebuilt the entire thing differently. Now I can rotate the cubeNode, but do little ease, so nothing with the lights or the camera unless I force a view refresh.

Comment: That is how SwiftUI is designed to behave. In your code `@State` doesn't work as you expect with the `class`/reference variables you have created (Value vs Reference variables) At the risk of being called snide again you should really look at the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) you need to use an appropriate SwiftUI wrapper to tell the View to reload. One option is to put your code in an `ObservableObject` and call `objectWillChange.send()` when you are ready for a refresh.

Comment: @loremipsum I don't really want to refresh the entire view [I used .id] because it flashes when I do. It fixes the issue, but badly. I also tried using an ObservableObject, but that doesn't work at all, aka it does nothing. I will look at it again using an objectWillChange.send call in the mix.

Comment: I also tried the some code in the render which almost works, only it fires too many times! Will add it to the code shown. If you run this code you note "duck" is printed out 14 times, despite the fact I try to reset it after the first call!